# Нарушение доступа для записи

Tags: c++

```
namespace MyNamespace{
    class MyClass
    {
        ...
    }; 
}   
MyNamespace::MyClass* TEST_VAL = NULL;
int getVal(MyNamespace::MyClass **val) {
  if (val == NULL)
    return 1;
  *val= TEST_VAL;
  return 0;
}
int main() {
    TEST_VAL = new MyNamespace::MyClass();
    MyNamespace::MyClass **val= new MyNamespace::MyClass*();
    return getVal(val);
}
```

В строке *val= TEST_VAL;
Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для записи.

val было 0xFFFFFFFFC54B2950.

Если для этого исключения имеется обработчик, выполнение программы может быть продолжено безопасно.
Подскажите пожалуйста как это поправить.

Comment: Согласно новым стандартам, вместо NULL рекомендуется использовать nullptr.

Comment: Вы точно все написали? Не воспроизводится что-то ваша неприятность ни в VC++2015, ни в [GCC](https://ideone.com/Zz3bqD)...

Comment: переопределен оператор new или даже глобально. Но плохо переопределен.

Comment: Забыл проинициализировать TEST_VAL. Теперь пример правильный.

Comment: приведите весь код, который у Вас. Может там такой конструктор, что ууууух.

Comment: @KoVadim Да нет, там скорее значение `val` какое-то странное...

Comment: тогда голосую за кастомный аллокатор или менеджер памяти внешний.

Answer (score 0):

Код не полный, а потому ошибки не видно. Между клиентом и сервером в json'е передавался указатель на указатель кастуемый к long. На Windows надо было кастовать к long long. Всем спасибо за попытку ответить на данный вопрос.

Comment: А может intptr_t? :)